# Exclude Java System properties and environment variables from SpringBoot configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties

Regarding the property resolution of SpringBoot explained here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

I want to exclude from the mechanism:

```
9.  Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
10. OS environment variables.
```

Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: any specific reason you want to do it? just to understand context

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide your own implementation of `StandardEnvironment` when instancing your Spring Boot application.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .environment(new StandardEnvironment(){
                @Override
                protected void customizePropertySources(MutablePropertySources propertySources) {
                    // do not add system or env properties to the set of property sources
                }
            });
    applicationBuilder.run(args);
}
```

Or alternatively:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
            .environment(new StandardEnvironment(){
                @Override
                public Map<String, Object> getSystemEnvironment() {
                    return new HashMap<>();
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, Object> getSystemProperties() {
                    return new HashMap<>();
                }
            });
    applicationBuilder.run(args);
}
```

Either way, you ensure that your application's properties do not contain any system or environment properties.

Comment: Another method I found useful in integration tests are to explicitly use `@TestPropertySource(value = "application-test.properties")` on a configuration test class and then import that configuration class to force the test properties to take precedence in the presence of any java system or environment variables that may override them.  Wasn't clear if OP was asking in context of testing.